# Suffixes and different stem words in transversarium and transversus?

Tags: declension, suffixes, biology, medicine

The difference between transversarium and transversus confuses me, this occurs with

- processus (masculine) transversus
- foramen (neutri) transversarium

where the endings, `sus` and `sa-ri-um`, are different such that

```
trans-ver-sus (3 syllables)
trans-ver-sa-ri-um (5 syllables)
```

and their stems are different, `trans-ver` and `trans-ver-sa-ri`.

The terms occurs in the cervical vertebra C6.

Please, explain the difference in the suffices and stems.

**Are the differences in suffixes and stems due to some declination rule?**

Answer (score 1):

While you're right that *transversus* is masculine and *transversarium* is neuter, the latter is not genitive, but these are actually two different words.

The first can be broken into three parts: trans-, vers-, and -us.

The second, however, into four: trans-, vers-, -ari-, -um.

The first is a pure past participle from *transverto* ("to turn away"). Here you would expect that the *processus* itself turns away.

*Transversarium* though adds the adjectival infix -ari-, which denotes a relationship to the verb *transverto*. This relationship could take a few forms, but the basic one is that it allows something else to be *transversus*.

Now, medical terminology is highly idiomatic, and I'm not a surgeon or medical historian, but if [this website](https://www.imaios.com/en/e-Anatomy/Anatomical-Parts/Foramen-transversarium) is accurate and I'm understanding it correctly, I think this bolded part explains the meaning:

> The transverse processes are each pierced by the *foramen transversarium*, which, in the upper six vertebræ, **gives passage** to the vertebral artery and vein and a plexus of sympathetic nerves.

It thus allows the vertebral artery and vein to "traverse" what I'm assuming are the transverse processes, though again, I am not a doctor, so hopefully someone with more medical knowledge can explain the action in greater detail.

A quick note on endings, the neuter genitive plural of *transversarium* is actually *transversariorum* (a mouthful!). *transversus* and *transversarium* are both 1-2 adjectives, and therefore follow the same inflection pattern, which you can see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transversus). Note that the second -s- is a part of the stem, not a part of the ending.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention other forms like *transversum* and *transversarius* to show that both adjectives have all genders (and cases). The endings are actually the same, so the only difference is in *-ari-*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I added a link instead. I'm a fan of not habitually reinventing the wheel! But feel free to edit to clarify if you think it really needs it.